# Aerospike cluster rebalancing causing errors

Tags: aerospike

When adding a new node to an Aerospike cluster, a rebalance happens for the new node. For large data sets this takes time and some requests to the new node fail until rebalance is complete. The only solution I could figure out is retry the request until it gets the data.

Is there a better way?

I don't think it is possible to keep the node out of cluster for requests until it's done replicating because it is also master for one of the partitions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing batch-reads, there is an improvement in 3.6.0.  While the cluster is in-flux, if the client directs the read transaction to Node_A, but the partition containing the record has been moved to Node_B, Node_A proxies the request to Node_B.

Is that what you are doing?

You should not be in a position where the client cannot connect to the cluster, or it cannot complete a transaction.

I know that SO frowns on this, but can you provide more detail about the failures? What kinds of transactions are you performing?  What versions are you using?

I hope this helps,

-DM

Answer (score 2):

Requests shouldn't be failing, the new node will proxy to the node that currently has the data.

Prior to [Aerospike 3.6.0](http://www.aerospike.com/download/server/notes.html#3.6.0) batch read requests were the exception. I suspect this is your problem.